# Appending SVG elements from SVG code

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dynamic-content

I have some base HTML like:

```
<body>
    <svg id="msvg"></svg>
<body>
```

I want to add (for example) a `<g><circle cx="10" cy="50" r="20"/><rect width="200" height="400" /> </g>`
Element into my SVG.

The element is given as a string in JavaScript.

I have thought about something like this:

```
function addSVG(svg) {
    var e = document.getElementById("msvg");
    var nodeelem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "template");
    nodeelem.innerHTML = svg;
    e.appendChild(nodeelem.content.firstChild);
}
```

But this doesn't work.

I am using Chromium Embedded, so a chrome-specific answer is good too.

Comment: There's no SVG element called template? What are you trying to do with "template"?

Comment: What the name implies: Use it as a template / placeholder.

Comment: "`Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function`"

Comment: There's no such thing in SVG. You've created an element named template which will have no defined functionality.

Comment: Please change `getElementByID` to `getElementById` ( D to d), `msg` to `e` and change `nodeelem.content.firstChild` to `nodeelem.firstChild` ! https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/su3xrfd9/

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Please post that( Especially the last tip ) as an answer, so I can accept it. I started from a similar function for HTML elements, where .content was necessary. The rest are copy errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the first child of `nodeelem`, you need to use `nodeelem.firstChild` instead of `nodeelem.content.firstChild`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/su3xrfd9/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is more than one way (and this one wont be the best ?), but you can try:

```
var svg = '<g><circle cx="10" cy="50" r="20"/><rect width="200" height="400" /> </g>';
var e = document.getElementById("msvg");
var svgObj = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(svg, 'application/xml');
e.innerHTML = svgObj.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Comment: The problem here is, that I need appending and not replacing. (for performance reasons) otherwise it would work without the DOMParser to.

Comment: @alkaltar the truth is- I wanted to append the document but I couln't figure out how I did this and din't want to spend much time finding a solution ;-)